# Can you access a css class' own attributes in calc?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I have a CSS class and want to use its width value to calculate its height like this:

```
.preview__card {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(([width of preview__card] * x) / y);
}
```

Is it possible to do it this way or do I need to use JavaScript? I have looked at a lot of calc() examples but cannot seem to find anything applicable.

Thank you :)

Comment: One of the first hits I saw was https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, with pure CSS solution - using CSS variables. Also, if your x and y variables are also dynamic, you could also change them into CSS variables.

Have a look at following article, it also shows you how you can modify CSS variables via JS, if needed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#values_in_javascript

```css
:root {
  --preview-card-width: 100%;
}

.preview__card {
  width: var(--preview-card-width);
  height: calc(var(--preview-card-width) * x) / y);
}
```

You could also take it further and make it a bit tidier.

```css
:root {
  --preview-card-width: 100%;
  --preview-card-height: calc(var(--preview-card-width) * x / y);
}

.preview__card {
  width: var(--preview-card-width);
  height: var(--preview-card-height);
}
```